# data-offset-bottom refresh issue on bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[data-offset-bottom refresh issue on bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEi8s.jpg)

I have a navbar fixed at top using the affix.js from bootstrap 3. My footer height is 1000px. When go to the footer and refresh the page (see the image) the navbar jumps to the footer. But when i scroll down or up, it resets to the top.

The bottom offset and the top are moving with the content smoothly, its just the page refresh causing this.

Can you help me.
Thanks!

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your work ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/. How do you refresh on fiddle?

Comment: have you tried class= "navbar-fixed-top" ?

Comment: Iam sorry iam new to fiddle, here's the proper code https://jsfiddle.net/Hive/DTcHh/13960/